# Is there an efficiency swarm Intelligence algorithm for off-chain channels routing in blockchain?

Tags: applications, swarm-intelligence, ant-colony-optimization, blockchain

One of the solutions to scale blockchain is to use off-chain channels. You can find its definition here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Off-Chain_Transactions.

However, one of the problems of off-chain channels is finding a suitable *decentralized routing* mechanism.

Since in Bitcoin there is no routing table and transactions are only broadcast and also, in general, we need to *avoid centralized* approaches for routing, is it practical to use swarm intelligence algorithms, such as ant colony optimization ones, for off-chain channels?

I refer you to a proposed ant routing algorithm in the paper [Ant routing algorithm for the Lightning Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.00151.pdf) for an instance of employing ACO algorithms for routing in _lightning network. However, the paper has not been evaluated to demonstrate its performance.